# Ubuntu 20.04 fails to recognize Intel UHD Graphics integrated GPU of i7-13620H processor

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

### Problem Description

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a mini PC equipped with an Intel Core i7-13620H processor, which features an integrated UHD Graphics GPU (Raptor Lake). However, the system seems unable to recognize my GPU properly. In Ubuntu settings, it displays `llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits)` instead of my UHD Graphics iGPU.

Furthermore, when I run `clinfo`, it outputs `Number of devices 0,` indicating that my GPU is not being detected. This issue is causing problems for me, particularly in an OpenVINO project where I need to use the GPU.

### System Information

- Ubuntu Version: 20.04
- Processor: Intel Core i7-13620H
- GPU: Intel UHD Graphics integrated GPU (Raptor Lake)
- Kernel-Version: 5.15.0-94-generic

### Methods Tried

(1) I attempted to install the driver package using the following command  (https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/driver/installation.html#install-steps):

```bash
sudo apt install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r) flex bison intel-fw-gpu intel-i915-dkms xpu-smi
```

(2) I also tried manually installing packages from the repository https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases. I attempted to install version `24.05.28454.6` release packages:

```bash
wget https://github.com/intel/intel-graphics-compiler/releases/download/igc-1.0.15985.7/intel-igc-core_1.0.15985.7_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/intel/intel-graphics-compiler/releases/download/igc-1.0.15985.7/intel-igc-opencl_1.0.15985.7_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/24.05.28454.6/intel-level-zero-gpu-dbgsym_1.3.28454.6_amd64.ddeb
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/24.05.28454.6/intel-level-zero-gpu_1.3.28454.6_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/24.05.28454.6/intel-opencl-icd-dbgsym_24.05.28454.6_amd64.ddeb
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/24.05.28454.6/intel-opencl-icd_24.05.28454.6_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/24.05.28454.6/libigdgmm12_22.3.11_amd64.deb
```

I'm still seeking suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found on github
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/AlbertVeli/8bf70de44daec9d7169f71c6a4a56fbf/raw/7da548ef32b9c8a0b4e0c78128a1435bad8282d2/oneapi.sh

## To make a long story short

## Install apt source as root

```
sudo su
curl -fsSL https://apt.repos.intel.com/intel-gpg-keys/GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS.PUB | sudo gpg --dearmor --output /usr/share/keyrings/intel-sw-products.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/intel-sw-products.gpg] https://apt.repos.intel.com/oneapi all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel-oneapi.list
apt update

# Install oneapi
apt install intel-oneapi-runtime-opencl intel-basekit clinfo opencl-headers

# source environment variableif want single session opencl

source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh

# Optional : if you want for every bash session
echo "source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```